# How to request from URL that is not Ember.js-conform?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, frontend

An unread count needs to be displayed in the navbar for our chat app. It can be requested under the following URL:

```
.../chats/get_unread_count
```

and the response is the following:

```
{
 "unread": 0
}
```

Since the URL is not conform to the Ember.js standard, I am unsure how to get Ember to request it under this URL. I ran out of ideas to try so I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of stuff we have [ember-ajax](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax). You can import this service in your component and then use it like you used to make ajax calls in e.g. jQuery

Here is an example:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  ajax: Ember.inject.service(),

  actions:  {
    makeRequest(params) {
      this.get('ajax').request('/chats/get_unread_count', {data: {params: params}}).
        then((repsonse) => {
          this.set('unreadCounts', response.unread);
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is this helping you? Would be great if you would give feedback in some form so others can benefit as well

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer! Your answer was indeed helpful, but I had to add a custom request header to include the authToken. In the end I used a [DRFAdapter](https://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/DataAdapterMixin.html) which automatically authorizes all outgoing API requests by injecting a header.